# PayPal PHP SDK 1.14 fatal error, cannot resolve error

Tags: php, api, paypal, sdk, runtime-error

The client wants PayPal PHP SDK 1.14 used in their business application even though 1.14 is deprecated and version 2 is the current supported version. Application is running in PHP 5.5.33.

Keep getting the following fatal error whenever trying to invoke the PayPal code:

> Fatal error: Interface 'PayPal\Common\IResource' not found in
> D:\xxxxxx\Library\PHP\PayPal-1.14.0\PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel.php
> on line 17

The problem is that IResource is in file PayPal\Rest\IResource.php, in the "Rest" folder, not in the "Common" folder. The "require_once" for IResource near the top of PayPalResourceModel.php even invokes IResource from the Rest folder. I don't know why the error message shows that the system is trying to invoke IResource from the Common folder and not finding it there (since it isn't supposed to be in Common).

Here's the top of the PayPalResourceModel.php program for reference:

```
<?php

namespace PayPal\Common;

require_once(PAYPAL_DIR . 'PayPal\Rest\ApiContext.php');
require_once(PAYPAL_DIR . 'PayPal\Rest\IResource.php');
require_once(PAYPAL_DIR . 'PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall.php');

/**
 * Class PayPalResourceModel
 * An Executable PayPalModel Class
 *
 * @property \PayPal\Api\Links[] links
 * @package PayPal\Common
 */
class PayPalResourceModel extends PayPalModel implements IResource
{
...
```

We cannot get past this fatal error whenever trying to run a program which references the PayPal code.

We aren't sure why the system is looking in the Common folder instead of in the Rest folder.

Does anyone have any suggestions for fixing this?

Thanks.
Doug

Comment: I'm wondering why your client is dictating the technology choices to that level of detail in the application you're creating for them. Can't you fight for using a supported version, on the basis that you're the programmer and they've presumably hired you because you know more about code than they do?

Comment: I agree. It's an application that we built and have been augmenting for many years (decades). We are adding a PayPal payment method to it. They wanted the v1 version of the PayPal API since it is a synchronous approach and therefore less to program (less expense), verses the v2 version which is an asynchronous implementation requiring more work. That is most of their reasoning. They don't usually reach "this low" into the technology choices (to them it's a cost choice). Any suggestions regarding this PHP error?

Comment: Can't you just change that reference to point to the right place? Obviously it's not ideal to mess with a 3rd party library, but if there's an obvious but minor bug...

Comment: Either that or check whether there's supposed to be another IResource in the place where it's missing, and it somehow didn't get downloaded with the rest of it

Comment: I cannot find a reference anywhere that references the file in the "wrong" place (if so, yes, changing that reference would be a good idea). It appears that the folder part of the path was implied or determined on-the-fly in some way(?), but where...